# How to multiply two rdds with out using mllib in scala ?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have sample code for matrix addition without using mllib

```
val result = rdd1.zip(rdd2)
    .map(y => {
     val res =  y._1.zip(y._2)
         .map { items: (Double, Double) =>
        (items._1 + items._2)
      }
      res.mkString(delimiter)
    })
```

Please help me to multiply two rdds

Comment: What is the problem you are facing here in the above code? Please elaborate

Comment: This code has no problem . But I don't know how this can be done for multiplication . This sample code is for addition not for multiplication

Comment: Matrix Multiplication where the Matrix are `RDD[Array[T]]` is not a trivial problem ( if you actually mean `Matrix Multiplication` and not the elment-wise multiplication). It will actually require a huge effort to accomplish even an acceptable solution. As far as I understand, you can forget about getting even a decent implementation without spending full 4-5 days on it. I will strongly advise you to use the mlib.

Comment: The reason being is that various operations in matrix multiplication require index based access of elements... which is very very in-efficient with RDD's. But you can start with a "beginner" solution based on the property `A(B+C) = AB+AC` of matrix multiplication.

Comment: break 1 of the matrices into many simpler matrices.

Comment: @AkhilaV I also  strongly recommend using MLLib's Matrix classes. You should not use collect as it may cause OutOfMemory on the driver and will be slow

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method to get the multiplied result.

```
  def mult[A](a: Array[Array[A]], b: Array[Array[A]])(implicit n: Numeric[A]): Array[Array[A]] = {
    import n._
    for (row <- a)
      yield for(col <- b.transpose)
        yield row zip col map Function.tupled(_*_) reduceLeft (_+_)
  }
```

[Reference](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Scala)

Comment: Thank you Jet 
Is this only possible for Array. How this can be applied to RDD[Array[Double]]

Comment: No . while using collect its changed to Array right ? 
By using Array, its not possible to use large files

Comment: @Jet Really? Never recommend to use collect as it will broke parallelism

Comment: This solution isn't Spark compatible. Collecting is encouraged unless the dataset is small and if the data is small to begin with, one shouldn't use spark.